# Display PDO array objects with calculated start and end variables

Tags: php, pdo

I would like to make use of Php PDO arrays. How can I display a whole row using a loop with start and end variables predefined? I dont know if this was asked but cant find something related with my problem now

My code is this

```
$sql = 'SELECT `casino_id`,`kiosk_id`,`kiosk_name`,`place`,`city`,`groups` FROM kiosk_data WHERE 1';

$result=$setsu->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
$dta=$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rwCnt=$result->rowCount();
$max=10;//display 10 records per page
$count = $rwCnt;
//$no is page no, which will determine which records to be shown on the current page
$start = ($no == 1)? 0 : ($no-1) * $max;
$end   = ($no * $max);
$data="<table>";
for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++){
    if($i >= $count){break;}
     $data.='<tr><td>'.$dta.'</td></tr>';
}
$data.="</table>";
echo $data;
```

Sample var_dump

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> array(6) { 
   ["casino_id"]=> string(1) "0" 
   ["kiosk_id"]=> string(4) "1" 
   ["kiosk_name"]=> string(5) "Tesla" 
   ["place"]=> NULL ["city"]=> NULL 
   ["groups"]=> NULL 
} 
[1]=> array(6) { 
  ["casino_id"]=> string(1) "0" 
  ["kiosk_id"]=> string(4) "2" 
  ["kiosk_name"]=> string(6) "Espada" 
  ["place"]=> NULL ["city"]=> NULL 
  ["groups"]=> NULL 
} 
[2]=> array(6) { 
 ["casino_id"]=> string(1) "0" 
 ["kiosk_id"]=> string(4) "3" 
 ["kiosk_name"]=> string(4) "Vlad" 
 ["place"]=> NULL ["city"]=> NULL 
 ["groups"]=> NULL 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++){
    if($i >= $count){break;}
    $data .= '<tr>';
    $data .= '<td>'.$dta[$i]['casino_id'].'</td>';
    $data .= '<td>'.$dta[$i]['kiosk_id'].'</td>';
    $data .= '<td>'.$dta[$i]['kiosk_name'].'</td>';
    $data .= '<td>'.$dta[$i]['place'].'</td>';
    $data .= '<td>'.$dta[$i]['groups'].'</td>';
    $data .= '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: This works but how about I have 10 more columns, is there a way without specifying the columns?